# How can I properly structure this Sequelize query?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

What I am trying to do is find a user by their username and also include whether or not they are a friend of the current user.

I would like to try and do this with one query so I can lessen the load on the server. I am leaning towards believing that I will have to do another query after I get the user by username in order to see if they are a friend or not.

```
exports.findUser = (req, res) => {

    //Get the username of the person to find
    var username = req.params.username.toLowerCase();

    if (!username) {
        //No username given
        res.status(400).send();
    } else if (username == req.user.get('username')) {
        //Send back a 400 because we dont want users thinking there is someone with their username
        res.status(400).send()
    }

    //Get a user where the username matches the one given
    db.user.findOne({
        where: {
            username: username
        },
        attributes: [
            "id",
            "username"
        ],
        include: [{
            model: db.friend,
            where: {
                //Or is used because we don't know who created the friendship
                $or: [
                    {
                        friendOneId: NEED THE ID OF THE USER IM SEARCHING,
                        friendTwoId: req.user.get('id')
                    }, 
                    {
                        friendOneId: req.user.get('id'),
                        friendTwoId: NEED THE ID OF THE USER IM SEARCHING
                    }
                ]
             }
        }]
    }).then(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            res.json(user);
        } else {
            res.status(404).send();
        }
    }, function(e) {
        res.status(500).send();
    });
};
```

Here is my friend model as requested

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    return sequelize.define('friend', {
        friendOneId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        },
        friendTwoId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but you can omit the: .toJSON(), only user is needed in the response

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Can you show us your friend model file? or the db structure?

Comment: @DZDomi I added it

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you just have to remove the AND from the different OR parts of the query, so basically:

```
where : {
     $or: [
         {
             friendTwoId: req.user.get('id')
         },          
         {       
             friendOneId: req.user.get('id'),
         }
     ]
},
required: false
```

In addition if you set the required attribute to false, the query will  also return all other users, even if the include query did not show any results

Comment: But that would fetch all friendships that I am apart of right? I just want to see if I am friends with the user I am searching for

Comment: I did not have luck with this

Comment: you should elaborate on your problem, what is showing with my query?

Comment: I tried this on an account where I was friends with the user I was searching for.  It is just giving me an empty array of friends.